# SWIG_NewPointerObj and values always being nil

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I'm using SWIG to wrap C++ objects for use in lua, and Im trying to pass data to a method in my lua script, but it always comes out as 'nil'

```
void CTestAI::UnitCreated(IUnit* unit){
    lua_getglobal(L, "ai");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "UnitCreated");
    swig_module_info *module = SWIG_GetModule( L );
    swig_type_info *type = SWIG_TypeQueryModule( module, module, "IUnit *" );
    SWIG_NewPointerObj(L,unit,type,0);
    lua_epcall(L, 1, 0);
}
```

Here is the lua code:

```
function AI:UnitCreated(unit)
   if(unit == nil) then
      game:SendToConsole("I CAN HAS nil ?")
   else
      game:SendToConsole("I CAN HAS UNITS!!!?")
   end
end
```

unit is always nil. I have checked and in the C++  code, the unit pointer is never invalid/null

I've also tried:

```
void CTestAI::UnitCreated(IUnit* unit){
    lua_getglobal(L, "ai");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "UnitCreated");
    SWIG_NewPointerObj(L,unit,SWIGTYPE_p_IUnit,0);
    lua_epcall(L, 1, 0);
}
```

with identical results.

Why is this failing? How do I fix it?

Comment: as a side note, changing the code so that I just have function UnitCreated in lua, and making the necessary changes to the C++ code works, but it does not if calling a function inside a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the colon in `function AI:UnitCreated(unit)`, it creates a hidden `self` parameter that receives the `AI` instance. It actually behaves like this:

```
function AI.UnitCreated(self, unit)
```

So when calling that function from C, you need to pass both parameters: the `ai` instance and the `unit` parameter. Since you passed only one parameter, `self` was set to it and `unit` was set to `nil`.

Comment: ah so calling getglobal("ai") and then pushing my swig pointer and doing 2 parameters should fix it? ^_^

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that should fix it.